# Want to create Alert dialog when TextView is clicked in list?

Tags: android, listview

I am having one tablerow with 4 textViews are in the list adapter.. The last(4th) Textview for the Quantity update.. if quantity textView is clicked want to create Alert dialog with one EditText, if value entered in edittext the value should display in TextView...In list multiple rows are there, want to edit that Quantity textview for all...

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: didn't understand the question.

Comment: @KingOmar want to enter a edittext value in textview when selected textview in list